# How to wait for Celery task result in asynchronous RestAPI?

Tags: python, redis, celery, python-asyncio, fastapi

I have an API build with FastAPI which endpoint submits a task to a celery worker, waits for worker to finish its job and return a result to the user.

Question is what is the correct way to wait the result?

Endpoint code

```
from tasks import celery_application, some_task
from celery.result import AsyncResult

@api.post('/submit')
async def submit(data: str):
    task = some_task.apply_async(kwargs={'data': data}, queue='some_queue')
    result = AsyncResult(id=task.task_id, app=celery_application).get()
    return {'task_result': result}
```

The problem with `AsyncResult` that it is that `get` method blocks the application, it waits for the result synchronously and the api freezes in the meantime.

One of the solutions I came up with is checking for result in a loop for n seconds

```
from tasks import celery_application, some_task
import asyncio
import redis


r = redis.Redis.from_url(REDIS_CONN_URI)


@api.post('/submit')
async def submit(data: str):
    task = some_task.apply_async(kwargs={'data': data}, queue='some_queue')
    result = None
    for _ in range(100):
        if r.exists(task.task_id):
            result = r.get(task.task_id)
            break
        await asyncio.sleep(0.3)

    return {'task_result': result}
```

But it only works partially. Although endpoint is not blocked and can be accessed. Endpoint gets blocked when it tries to reach send task again.

Comment: does the second approach unblock the API and the more requests can be made without piling up?

Comment: yes, it unblocks every 0.3 sec, so api is available and it is possible to submit additional requests. The solution to piling up would be to celery worker scaling.

Comment: The solution to not blocking your API is actually run the tasks in the background and not wait on their result. Return the task ID from Celery and create a new endpoint which allows you to poll the task status. Once the task is complete you can get the result in another endpoint.

Comment: @im_baby So basically the user that is requesting the api needs to spam that other api endpoint for the result?

Comment: Yes that is a solid way for longer background tasks. From the first endpoint return the link to check the status and/or result. From the status endpoint you can poll the task status then return the task result, or a final link to the results.